# Double/Triple loading jquery dialog, javascript code inside ajax loaded form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I've getting the following error and I don't know how to fix it. I'm using codeigniter framework, I'm building an admin site, this side has a number of sections to administrate, in each section you can create, edit, translate or delete items. Each time I want to do any of these actions I get a form using Ajax, then I load it on a jquery Dialog, but if I want to include some javascript inside the dialog, it will load a total of 3 times, showing only the header of the dialog in the last 3 times. When I remove the javascript code inside the form, it loads perfect, just one time.

For instance, this is my news form:

```
<div id="create-form">      
<?=form_open('news/'.$action); ?>   
    <?php $sindex = 0?> 
    <table class="table-content-right width800px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="not-for-edit">
            <td class="padding-10px" valign="top">
                <span>SELECT LANG:</span>
            </td>
            <td class="padding-10px">
                <select id="cmbTextTranslate" name="cmbTextTranslate">                  
                    <?php foreach($languages as $language) :?>
                        <?php if (($language->active == 1) && ($language->oid != $this->session->userdata('lang'))):?>                                                          
                            <option value='<?= $language->oid?>'><?= strtoupper($language->oid)?></option>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>
                <img class="imgLangTranslate" src="" />
            </td> 
        </tr>           
        <tr class="color-grey-soft-light color-black currentlang" valign="top">
            <td class="padding-10px">TITLE: <img class="not-for-edit" src="<?=base_url()?>img/flags/en.gif" /></td>
            <td class="padding-10px"><input id="title_en" name="title_en" class="input-border" type="text" value="<?= (isset($new) ? $new->title_en : "") ?>" /></td>               
            <td class="padding-10px"><span sindex="<?= $sindex++;?>" class="color-error"></span></td>               
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($languages as $language) :?>
            <?php if (($language->active == 1) && ($language->oid != $this->session->userdata('lang'))):?>
                <tr class="not-for-edit" translateTo="<?= $language->oid?>" valign="top">
                    <td class="padding-10px" valign="top">TITLE_<?= $language->oid?>: <img class="translateToFlag" src="" /></td>
                    <td class="padding-10px" valign="top"><input class="input-border input-translate" id="title_<?= $language->oid?>" name="title_<?= $language->oid?>" type="text" value="<?= (isset($new) ? $new->title_es : "") ?>"/></td>                       
                </tr>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        <tr class="currentlang" valign="top"><td class="padding-10px">BODY: <img class="not-for-edit" src="<?=base_url()?>img/flags/en.gif" /></td>
            <td id="textarea-td" class="padding-10px">
                <textarea rows="5" id="body_en" class="input-border" name="body_en"><?= (isset($new) ? $new->body_en : "") ?></textarea>
            </td>               
            <td class="padding-10px"><span sindex="<?=$sindex++;?>" class="color-error"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($languages as $language) :?>
            <?php if (($language->active == 1) && ($language->oid != $this->session->userdata('lang'))):?>
                <tr class="not-for-edit" translateTo="<?= $language->oid?>" valign="top">
                    <td class="padding-10px" valign="top">BODY_<?= $language->oid?>: <img class="translateToFlag" src="" /></td>
                    <td id="textarea-td_<?=$language->oid?>" class="padding-10px">
                        <textarea rows="5" id="body_<?=$language->oid?>" class="input-border" name="body_<?=$language->oid?>"><?= (isset($new) ? $new->body_es : "") ?></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </table>
    <input id="oid" name="oid" type="hidden" value="<?= (isset($new) ? $new->oid : "") ?>" />
</form>
```

And if I add the following block at the end of the file the error start:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

It doesn't matter if it is empty, or filled with code inside, it always give me the same error.

This is the code I have for calling that form:

```
    $("#btnCreate").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        url: 'news/load_form/create',
        success: function(data) {
            //$(data).dialog(config.dialog);                
            $(data).dialog($.extend(config.dialog, 
                {title: 'CREATE NEW',
                 open: function() {
                     alert('cuantas veces'); 
                 },
                 close: function() {
                     $(this).dialog('destroy');
                 },
                 buttons: [
                      {     text:'CREATE',
                            click: function() {                 
                            if ($("form").submit() === true)                    
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        {   text: 'RESET',
                            click: function() {                             
                                $("#create-form input[type='text']").val("");
                            }
                        },
                        {   text: 'CANCEL',
                            click: function() {                             
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })                  
            );
            $('.not-for-edit').hide();

            tinyMCE.init($.extend(config.tinyMCE.writtable,
                {oninit: function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, 'body_<?= $this->session->userdata('lang')?>');
                        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, 'body_<?= $this->session->userdata('lang')?>');
                    }, 1000)}
                })
            );
        }
    });     
});
```

I don't really understand the problem, it seems right to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, your HTML is invalid in the view code, e.g. missing a closing </div> for the #create-form element.